# NSSelectorFromString

Tags: objective-c, selector

Is there something wrong with this code? I'm trying to set up some buttons by defining at run time the label, the callback selector, and, later, a pointer to the UIButton itself.  But with this code, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. It gos away if I delete the line with NSSelectorFromString. But since this is just an object being added to the dictionary, I don't understand shy it fails.

```
NSMutableDictionary *attachButtonDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        @"Attach To Job",@"keyForLabel",
                                        NSSelectorFromString(@"attachToJob"), @"keyForSelector",
                                        nil];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a selector is not an objc object; a selector is an opaque representation of a method name.

the program will crash when adding it to the dictionary because it cannot be messaged. for example, it cannot be retained when added.

Comment: I’d say a selector is more like an opaque representation of a method name.

Comment: I have never heard the term "opaque representation". Where can i read more about that?

Comment: you are likely familiar with opaque data types: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type` and opaque pointers: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer`. an 'opaque representation' is similar, but a more general term. OPs and ODTs are types of opaque representations.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot store the `selector` into your `NSDictionary`.

Just store the string and when you build your button call `NSSelectorFromString()`.

Best,
Christian

Edit:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attachButtonDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                @"Attach To Job",@"keyForLabel",
                                                @"attachToJob", @"keyForSelector",
                                                nil];

UIButton *fancyButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[fancyButton addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString([attachButtonDictionary objectForKey:@"keyForSelector"]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can't store a selector in a dictionary, you can wrap it in a NSValue.

```
SEL fooSel = @selector(foo);
NSValue *selWrapper = [NSValue valueWithPointer:fooSel];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:selWrapper 
                                                               forKey:@"foo"];
SEL myFooSel = [[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] pointerValue];
[obj performSelector:myFooSel];
```